# How to bypass SQL Server caching

Tags: sql-server, caching

When I am trying to examine the performance of a given query in my application I'm generally uninterested in the effect *my* code is having.  I want to be able to watch the time taken in Sql Management Studio.

Unfortunately, I'm finding that some sort of caching *must* be going on, because one query that returns 10,000 results from a table with 26 or so columns, many of them large varchars, takes 12 seconds the first time I run it in a while and takes 6 seconds the following times unless I don't re-run it for a few minutes.

Is there any way to instruct it to bypass the cache and pretend like it had never run it before? I'm using SQL Server 10.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clean out the cache and sproc cache with

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

respectively

Comment: +1 And you could add a `checkpoint` in there as well (before `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`) just for good measure.

Comment: You can confirm your suspicions by using set statistics io on and examining the output.  Specifically, compare the physical reads to logical reads.